# Unable to start minikube on Mac M1 with docker

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to start minikube on a Mac M1 (macOs Monterey V12.0.1) after installing minikube with homebrew (`brew install minikube`) but I am getting an error after running `minikube start`.

The error in the logs is this one:

```
  initialization failed, will try again: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.22.3:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.22.3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks

stderr:
    [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR KubeletVersion]: couldn't get kubelet version: cannot execute 'kubelet --version': exit status 255
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher


  Error starting cluster: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.22.3:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.22.3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks

stderr:
    [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR KubeletVersion]: couldn't get kubelet version: cannot execute 'kubelet --version': exit status 255
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher


╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                             │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                           │
│                                                                                           │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

❌  Exiting due to GUEST_START: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.22.3:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.22.3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks

stderr:
    [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR KubeletVersion]: couldn't get kubelet version: cannot execute 'kubelet --version': exit status 255
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher


╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                             │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                           │
│                                                                                           │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

I have tried enabling kubelet.service by running `sysctl enable kubelet.service` but didn't change anything. I have also kubeclt version `1.22` installed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to my problem, although, I'm not really sure what was the main issue, it seems that it was related to old configurations in the `.minikube` folder in the users' home directory.

To fix it, first I had to enabled Kubernetes in docker desktop, and then I had to stop and delete minikube cluster, and finally delete the directory. Then running the command again was successful.

To fix:

```sh
$ minikube stop
$ minikube delete
$ rm -rf ~/.minikube/
$ minikube start

  minikube v1.24.0 on Darwin 12.0.1 (arm64)
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=1988MB) ...
    > kubectl.sha256: 64 B / 64 B [--------------------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > kubelet.sha256: 64 B / 64 B [--------------------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > kubeadm.sha256: 64 B / 64 B [--------------------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > kubeadm: 40.50 MiB / 40.50 MiB [-------------] 100.00% 29.75 MiB p/s 1.6s
    > kubectl: 41.44 MiB / 41.44 MiB [-------------] 100.00% 21.39 MiB p/s 2.1s
    > kubelet: 107.26 MiB / 107.26 MiB [-----------] 100.00% 27.70 MiB p/s 4.1s

    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
    ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

Comment: These same steps worked for me on a Mac M1

Comment: Worked for me on a Mac AMD

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on mac m1-
`$ minikube delete --all`
`$ rm -rf ~/.minikube`
`$ minikube start --force-systemd=true`

reference-
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/faq/#docker-driver-how-can-i-set-minikubes-cgroup-manager

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming across this problem:

1. Make sure you're using the arm64 binary of minikube
2. Run `minikube delete --all --purge`
3. Try starting minikube again

Answer (score 0):

First the Mac Machine is enabling swap by default. You have to disable swap then retry to start minikube

Steps to disable swap in MacBook:

- **1. Disable SIP:**
- Power-off MacBook first,
- hold Command (⌘) and R, and then start-up the MacBook.
  *(For M1 chip based MacBook, hold the power button until seeing “Loading startup options”)*.
  You should see a macOS utilities window.
- From the utilities menu, select “Terminal” then, Run `csrutil disable` the screen should display a message that SIP is already disabled.
  [image]
- From the  menu, press restart to restart MacBook.
- **2. Disable swap**
- open The macbook terminal
- check the current mode that system manages memory, type `sysctl -a vm.compressor_mode` in terminal.
- The default mode is **4**, which represents compressing memory and using swap. To disable swap, we should change the mode from **4** to **2**, which means compressing memory only.
- modify vm.compressor_mode, type `sudo nvram boot-args="vm_compressor=2"`. The mode won’t be changed until reboot.
  -reboot

Again, anyone running computer without swap file should monitor memory usage carefully to avoid kernel panic!

- **3. Minikube start:**

```html
$ minikube stop
$ minikube delete
$ rm -rf ~/.minikube/
$ minikube start
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a red-herring because your running the x86 minikube.   Some reasons why that could happen are here:  [Homebrew installs wrong minikube (amd64) instead of 'arm64' on m1 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654675/homebrew-installs-wrong-minikube-amd64-instead-of-arm64-on-m1-mac/76584586#76584586)